# multiple instance of same object running in multithread, how do i prevent to change a global variable by all threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, pthreads

I have a class named myConsumer and it has a function getDataFromBuffer(). I create multiple instance of the object consumer1, consumer2, consumer3 from my class. Each consumer objects are running in different thread concurrently. Everything is okay until here. But i want to add something. I have a global variable named MyGlob, I want to increase its value by one, it getDataFromBuffer() function is used by consumer1 in that time. And I want to not change the other threads MyGlob variable. How to prevent the others changing my value?

I summerize my problem:

```
int MyGlob;

class myConsumer
{
public:
    void getDataFromBuffer();
}

void myConsumer::getDataFromBuffer(){
    if(this function is used by consumer1 )
        myGlob++;
}
```

I am using pthread library for thread on windows and eclipse cdt

Comment: You could simply create `consumer1` with a flag that tells it that it is special, or pass in an explicit reference/pointer to `myGlob`.

Comment: Could you explain some detail? I am very new in multithreading. How to set a flag? @Botje

Comment: Alter the constructor of `myConsumer` to take an extra `bool` argument. Store it in a class member and check in `getDataFromBuffer`. Finally, pass `true` when creating `consumer1`. No special thread knowledge necessary.

Comment: I did it. I create an integer variable int myCon; to myConsumer. if it is consumer1 i set it 1. And check this value inside the function. But i am not completely sure it is true method. Are you sure it is right usage?

Comment: It is the simplest possible solution. Whether it is "right" depends on you. You never told us why you wanted to treat consumer1 differently, so there might be a better mechanism still.